# ADDS: Mandatory Profiles through powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, user-profile

***Intro*** 
I'm a networking student from Belgium and I just got assigned a big project.
Basicly i'm responsible for the ADDS. We have to create several OU's and every OU needs at least 20 users or more. 
1 of these OU's is called "Guests" and has 20+ guests in them. All these "Guests" profiles need to be mandatory (and I know how to create them).

## My Question

Is there a way to create mandatory profiles through Windows Powershell or maybe group policies. Because doing +20 profiles manually is going to take a lot of work and it might be easier than I think.

### Details

All Clients are Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 
Windows Server 2012 (DC)
Windows Server 2012 (ADC)
All other profiles are Roaming Profiles (except for admin)
Profiles are stored on both servers using DFS for redundancy
The script I use just creates the Tree mapping. F.E:
Domain.local --> Domain --> OU--> inside this map you wil find:
OU_Group_DomainLocal
OU_Group_Global
All_OU_Users 
And this for all OUs.

### Confusion Edit

I have not created any users yet, I'm going to create all my users through Powershell. I was wondering if there was an automatic way to create Mandatory profiles, instead of going in the regedit and edit a bunch of stuff for every user seperatly.

Comment: Not sure I understand - you've already created the .man profiles and need a way to automatically assign them to the users in the Guests OU? Or you need to automate the creation of the actual profile file?

Comment: [Not sure what you've looked at so far](http://serverfault.com/questions/542772/is-there-a-simpler-method-for-creating-mandatory-profiles-for-windows-7-users), but you would probably need to create the first profile by hand, then you should be able to use that, and Group Policy to handle the others. If you put the default profile on a Server, you should be able to assign it to the ADUser Object with PowerShell.

Comment: No, I have not created anything yet. I just need 20+ Mandatory profiles. I'm looking for a way to create these profiles automaticly, and not just by going into regedit and change a bunch of stuff. 
I don't care how I need to do it, I was asking if there was an automatic way instead of a manual one

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy powershell profiles using group policy:
1. Prepare the profile.ps1 file
2. Copy it to a shared folder
3. then go to group policy --> User Configuration --> Preferences --> Windows Settings --> Files 
see [this Technet Blog entry for more details](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fun_with_powershell/archive/2013/06/27/how-do-we-customize-the-powershell-profile-to-start-the-transcript.aspx)

Comment: I think this question is dealing with actual User Profiles, not the PowerShell $profile.

Comment: Yes, wat mortenya says